# Definition of the fourth normal form in normalization

Tags: database, relational-database, relation, database-normalization

I've got a question regarding the fourth normal form (4NF).
I'm a little confused since I saw some definitions and some of these differ from one another.

The easiest definition I saw was this one: [Translated from the German Wikipedia] — [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form):

> A table is in 4NF if it is in Boyce–Codd normal form (BCNF) and only contains trivial multivalued dependencies (MVDs).

Using the definition of a MVD from Wikipedia
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_dependency)

[image: MVD]

A trivial MVP is according to Wikipedia:

> A multivalued dependency X ->> Y is trivial if Y is a subset of X,  or
>   if X ∪ Y is the whole set of attributes of the relation.

Using this definition, the following table should not be in 4NF:

```
CourseNr Book     Lecturer
======== ====     ========
1        Math-A   Prof. Smith
1        Math-B   Prof. Bob
1        Math-A   Prof. Bob
1        Math-B   Prof. Smith
```

This is pretty much the definition from the Wikipedia.
My question is now:
If I remove the last line from this table:

```
CourseNr Book     Lecturer
======== ====     ========
1        Math-A   Prof. Smith
1        Math-B   Prof. Bob
1        Math-A   Prof. Bob
```

If this table now in 4NF?
I would say yes, because it doesn't fit the definition of 
multivalued dependency any more and thus the table doesn't contain 
a trivial MVD anymore and should thus be in 4NF.

Is my assumption correct or did I make a mistake along the way?

Comment: I always find that 4NF is pretty easy to understand as long as you stay away from the textbook/normalization nomenclature. Try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2tQZ9H1skg

Comment: Watched the video, and though I do understand what he is and explaining and what the 4. NF is all about and how to "achieve" it, it still bothers me a bit that I have some problems with the formal definition of the 4. NF. But maybe I should stop trying to understand the formal definiton at all events and just start using the non-formal explanation of the video. (As Brian Finnegan in the video says: "you can now tell people that you understand that you need to as a competent data modeler about the 4.NF"). Anyway, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Re posting, please use text whenever possible. Parts of images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. And questions should be self-contained. (If you want to use special characters see wiki List_of_Unicode_characters, in particular the math links.)

Comment: You don't mean "this is pretty much the definition [of 4NF] from the Wikipedia", you mean "this satisfies" it. And what are you trying to say by adding "pretty much", since it either does or doesn't? What does "it doesn't fit the definition of multivalued dependency anymore" mean, since "it" is a table? How does that lead to "thus the table doesn't contain a trivial MVD anymore"? Do you mean, *non*-trivial? How does that lead to "and should thus be in 4.NF"?

Comment: PS The last table actually satisfies some non-trivial FDs & MVDs, determining CourseNr. Presumably you are thinking in terms of the variable holding that value, not satisfying those FDs/MVDs, having had an MVD constraint dropped.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 1):

> A table is in 4NF if it is in Boyce–Codd normal form and only contains trivial multi-valued dependencies (MVDs).

This uses "only" poorly. Also, its use of "contains" is perhaps vague in a beginner's context. It seems to be trying to say:

- A table is in 4NF if it is in BCNF and the only MVDs it satisfies are trivial.

However, that is wrong.

If FD X → Y holds then MVD X ↠ Y holds. (It is often said that a FD is a MVD, but that is incorrect. FDs & MVDs are expressions with arrows. But the FD states a more restricted condition than the MVD does.) Informally, while the MVD says that all of some subrow values for Y must appear with all of some subrow values of X, the FD says that set of all Y subrows has only one element.

Correct descriptions along these lines are:

- A table is in 4NF if it is in BCNF and every MVD it satisfies is trivial or corresponds to a FD.
- A table is in 4NF if it is in BCNF and every MVD it satisfies that doesn't correspond to a FD is trivial.

(Don't use Wikipedia as a technical reference, only as a supplement. In particular most entries re the relational model have errors and confusions.)

(See my answers re 4NF & MVDs.)